# ¿Se pueden tener sockets en un API Rest en Node js?

Tags: nodejs, express, rest, socket.io

Tengo un Api Rest en nodejs con express funcionando perfectamente, pero me surgió la necesidad de mandar una notificación a frontend sin la interacción del usuario por lo que quise implementar un socket con socket.io, hice una aplicacion de prueba en donde funcionó sin problemas, pero al momento de integrar el socket a mi api que ya tenía no funcionó, como si el servidor estuviera caído para el socket, pero funcionan las peticiones Rest. Esta es una versión resumida del api rest:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express()

var rutas = require('./routes/rutas.routes');

app.use((req, res, next) => {
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
res.header('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
next();
});

app.use('/api', rutas);

module.exports = app;
```

Quise poner el socket de esta forma:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express()

var server = require("http").Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(server);

var rutas = require('./routes/rutas.routes');

app.use((req, res, next) => {
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
res.header('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
next();
});

io.on("connection", function (socket) {
console.log("Conexion por socket");
socket.emit("messages", {messages: "hola mundo"});
});

app.use('/api', rutas);

module.exports = app;
```

En algunas ocasiones pone el "Conexion por socket" en consola pero no manda el emit al frontend, No se si esto es posible en primer lugar, ¿es posible tener sockets y Rest de esta forma? ¿tengo que hacer un servidor propio para los sockets? Agradeceria sus comentarios, Gracias.

Comment: Claro que es posible. La pregunta es ¿has configurado el cliente? Porque para que el cliente reciba el mensaje debe estar conectado al socket.

Comment: Claro que si, el cliente manda el siguiente error "WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed:" como si no hubiera levantado el servidor